# Realtime collaboration MODE comments

Tags: reactjs, angular

we are using RealTimeCollaborativeComments plugin in editor for the real-time collaboration comments.
we have own other functionality on basis of real-time collaborative comments .so we want custom adaptor also we try with the RealTimeCollaborativeComments plugin and custom adaptor but got an error. I have attached error in attachments .so is there any way to using RealTimeCollaborativeComments plugin and custom adaptor we handle the real time collaboration comment ???
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtOwI.png)

I try with the RealTimeCollaborativeComments plugin but it is working in collaboration mode. But we want particular type of data and with help of custom  adaptor we can achieve in anluar JS.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.